# how to fetch multiple records from 1 object

Tags: controller

I have a controller **`ValidUI`** which is verifying user name & password from Freelancer object. But when I have only 1 record it is working fine but for other records it is showing the error message i have given. suggestions please

```
public class ValidUI {
    public String password {get;set;}
    public String username {get;set;}
    public List < Freelancer__c > FreelancerList {get;set;}
    public Freelancer__c fre {get;set;}
    public PageReference registerUser() {
        {
            fre = [select User_Name__c, Password__c from Freelancer__c limit 1];
            System.debug('++++' + fre);
            if (UserName == fre.User_Name__c && Password == fre.Password__c) {
                PageReference newPage = new PageReference('http://myatsui-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/referralHome');
                newPage.setRedirect(true);
                return newPage;
            } else {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'TRY AGAIN... .'));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are saying if you have only 1 record, It is working fine. So, You didn't write the coding for handling multiple files...And you mentioned only what is going on over there but you didn't exactly mention what you want... Some more info needs for this question...

Comment: I have 1 object Freelancer where in different records user name & passwords are stored. in the login page  if i enter any user name & password it will verify with the Freelancer object if the data is correct then it will redirect to other page if not then it will show error message. I have multiple records. but for only 1 record this is working for other records it is showing error message.

Comment: Got it. Because you have given the Query for Freelancer__c Object and put the LIMIT 1 so that it is taking 1 record everytime and checking for that username and password match. If matches then entering otherwise showing error.

Comment: Your function name should be `validateUser` not `registerUser` here you are just validating details not doing any insertion things;

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, this will direcly check in the database you will not require any extra work to do. Fetching multiple records and the comparison will be done by database server. Using this way will increase execution time.

```
public class ValidUI {
        public String password {get;set;}
        public String username {get;set;}
        public PageReference registerUser() {
                List<Freelancer__c> freelancersList = [SELECT Id
                                                     FROM Freelancer__c 
                                                     WHERE User_Name__c = :UserName
                                                     AND Password__c = :Password];

                //If there is user in database
                if(!freelancersList.isEmpty()) {
                     PageReference newPage = new PageReference('http://myatsui-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/referralHome');
                    newPage.setRedirect(true);
                    return newPage;
                } else {
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'TRY AGAIN... .'));
                }
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the Query correctly....@Ishwar Mete. I am seeing there is wrong in your query...

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

```
public class ValidUI {
    public String password {get;set;}
    public String username {get;set;}
    public List<Freelancer__c> FreelancerList {get;set;}
    public List<Freelancer__c> fre {get;set;}
    public PageReference registerUser() {
        {
            fre = [SELECT User_Name__c, Password__c FROM FreeLancer__c];
            for(Freelancer__c fr : fre){
                if (UserName == fr.User_Name__c && Password == fr.Password__c) {
                    PageReference newPage = new PageReference('http://myatsui-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/referralHome');
                    newPage.setRedirect(true);
                return newPage;
                } else {
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'TRY AGAIN... .'));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
public class ValidUI {
    public String password {get;set;}
    public String username {get;set;}
    public List<Freelancer__c> FreelancerList {get;set;}
    public List<Freelancer__c> fre {get;set;}
    public PageReference registerUser() {
        {
            fre = [SELECT User_Name__c, Password__c FROM FreeLancer__c WHERE User_Name__c = :UserName AND Password__c = :Password LIMIT 1];
            if (fre.size()>0) {
                PageReference newPage = new PageReference('http://myatsui-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/referralHome');
                newPage.setRedirect(true);
                return newPage;
            } else {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'TRY AGAIN... .'));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you added **Method 1:**?

Comment: Method 1 will query all the records and then compare the Username and Password with given inputs. Method 2 will Query the records which matched to the Username and Password Given and then do the process...Both comes to the same result but based on the query, i have the given the next process...

Comment: That's fine. Will you try **Method 1:** in your project and why?

Comment: In method 2 I don't you need fields User_Name__c, Password__c just fetching Id would work perfectly